# Send two parameters from controller to Ajax | Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a question is it possible to send two parameters from controller to Ajax for view?

I have two variables that store data

I need an optimal solution

I tried:

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetDepartmentAndManager(string userId)
        {

            var danePracownika = _uzytkownicyContext.Uzytkownicy
                                                    .Where(x => x.Id == IntIdCzlowieka)
                                                    .Select(s => new
                                                    {
                                                        UserDepartament = s.Departament,
                                                        UserManager = s.ManagerLogin

                                                    });


            var userDetailsAU = _ecpContext.AC_Merge_V
                                           .Where(x => x.Id == IntIdCzlowieka)
                                           .Select(s => new
                                           {
                                               WymiarEtatu = s.WymiarEtatu,
                                               NormaDzienna = s.NormaDzienna

                                           });


            return Json(danePracownika, userDetailsAU);
        }
```

**Ajax | javascript / View:**

```
  $.ajax({

            url: "@Url.Action("GetDepartmentAndManager", "Uzytkownicy")",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {"userId": JSON.stringify(userId)},
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, user) {
                $("#Id_department")
                    .dxTextBox("instance")
                    .option("value", data[0].UserDepartament);
                $("#Id_manager")
                    .dxTextBox("instance")
                   .option("value", data[0].UserManager);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return those values as properties on an object:

```
return Json(new { data = danePracownika, user = userDetailsAU });
```

Then in the response they will be properties on the result:

```
success: function (result) {
    $("#Id_department")
        .dxTextBox("instance")
        .option("value", result.data[0].UserDepartament);
    $("#Id_manager")
        .dxTextBox("instance")
        .option("value", result.data[0].UserManager);
    // I assume you also want to use result.user somewhere...
}
```